# Adding images to nav bar overflows into form email signin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the standard template http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html per bootstrap and but when I add icons my nav bar runs into my form for email signin.

How can I prevent this (use margin/padding or adjust the body width)?

If so how?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's because navbar has fixed width.

Comment: @SteelRat: thx for reply. what workaround could I apply here?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted but looks like container-fluid did the trick.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    **<div class="container-fluid">**
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigations links are encroaching to the form panel at the top, i have some alternatives try any of these:-

1. Add more width to the container so that form panel will adjust automatically.
2. Can reduce the size of input boxes by adding classes like `input-mini, input-small, input-medium, span1, span2, span3` to the input boxes.
3. Also you can adjust margin/padding to left/right of the navigation links.

Thanks hope this will help you...